# Ajax HTTP Response to update

Tags: javascript, ajax

How does an Ajax HTTP response look like. I am note sure if its in `xml` or as a `div` tag. I know its not in html as it is only updating a section of html page. So if a simple web page with a text field value change and an area of a page is to be updated as a result of text change in field, how does the body construct of the AJAX response look like?

```
HTTP / 1.1     200    OK
Content-Type: text/plain
...
...


BODY?
```

Comment: The response text should be in the `.responseText` property of the original XHR object. Is that what you mean? Your question lacks information.

Comment: Or, use 204 No Content if you just need to indicate things were successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ajax response will be whatever the server returns to the client if you print html the response will be in html if you print xml the return will be xml...

```
<?php
echo "<div>Some text</div>";
?>
```

The response will be:

```
<div>Some text</div>
```

Comment: so just the div tag in the body of the response, so how does it know the id of the div tag if you dont mind answering?

Comment: which div id you want to know? if you <?php
echo '<div id="some_div">Some text</div>';
?> the id of your returned div is some_div

Comment: ok great:D, if content-type is text/plain will the response be just words with no tag?

Comment: if you want to send back a plain text just send it back <?php echo "this is a text";?> your response will be plain text.

Answer (score 0):

All Ajax I've used responds with JSON. If you use chrome you can check the response in DevTools.

This answer is on my mobile, I'll fill out more from home.